# Como cerrar conexión de mongo después de un fetch

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, cron

Estoy realizando una función en Node.js que con Node-Cron realiza varias peticiones anidadas a una api y finalmente con la respuesta conecto a mongodb y la guardo en una base de datos.

Todo funciona bien excepto que si le indico que cierre la base de datos (incluso con un setTimeout para asegurarme que se hayan realizado todas las actualizaciones) node me peta, pero si no lo hago se van creando conexiones cada 30 min.

Ya indico que soy bastante novato en javaScript y me estoy metiendo en algo que se que me queda grande, pero que no se diga que no lo intento.
Este es el codigo:

```
cron.schedule('30 * * * *', function () {
    console.log("actualizando");
    searchGuardianes();
});

function searchGuardianes() {

    mongo.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        console.log("Conectado a bd");
        var dbo = db.db("destiny");

        fetch('https://www.bungie.net/Platform/GroupV2/624280/Members/', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "X-API-KEY": "miapi"
            }
        })
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(function (data) {

                    data.Response.results.forEach(function (element) {
                        var id = element.destinyUserInfo.membershipId;

                        fetch('https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny2/2/Profile/' + id + '/?components=100', {
                            method: 'GET',
                            headers: {
                                "X-API-KEY": "miapi"
                            }
                        })
                                .then(function (response) {
                                    return response.json();
                                })
                                .then(function (data) {

                                    data.Response.profile.data.characterIds.forEach(function (car) {
                                        var caracteres = car;

                                        //console.log(id, caracteres);
                                        //Aqui ya tengo todos los ids y profiles. voy a por activities

                                        fetch('https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny2/2/Account/' + id + '/Character/' + caracteres + '/Stats/Activities/?count=100', {
                                            method: 'GET',
                                            headers: {
                                                "X-API-KEY": "miapi"
                                            }
                                        })
                                                .then(function (response) {
                                                    return response.json();
                                                })
                                                .then(function (data) {

                                                    data.Response.activities.forEach(function (actividades) {

                                                        dbo.collection("guardianes").update(
                                                                {
                                                                    _id: id
                                                                }, {
                                                            $addToSet: {
                                                                actividades: actividades
                                                            }
                                                        }, function (err, res) {
                                                            if (err)
                                                                throw err;
                                                        });


                                                    });

                                                })
                                                .catch(function (err) {
                                                    console.log(err);
                                                });

                                    });
                                })
                                .catch(function (err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                });
                    });

                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });

//        setTimeout(function(){
//            db.close();
//        }, 50000);
    });

}
```

Agradezco cualquier consejo para poder cerrar las conexiones creadas sin que implique el fin de la aplicación.
Un saludo,

Comment: El problema es que **JavaScript** no funciona de esa manera, **JavaScript** es un lenguaje asíncrono osea no funciona de una manera en la que acaba un suceso y continua otro, puede ejecutar un suceso y sin terminarlo continuar con lo siguiente, a mi parecer deberías consultar que es un **callback**
también como estas utilizando promesas, buscar que son y como funcionan ahora la solución para cerrar la `db` no es cerrarla después del `fetch` sino dentro ya que se cierra sin que la petición `get` terminara (por eso de que un suceso puede continuar sin que otro no terminara)

Comment: Aunque tarde por mi parte... muchas gracias! Investigando, descubrí que la base de datos no debía abrirla y cerrarla con cada consulta o actualización, simplemente lo solucione arrancando db al iniciar el servidor.